# Avoiding specific PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception to allow script to continue running

Tags: php, exception

I would like to make it so that my scripts can continue to run even if there's a CERTAIN fatal error. Right now I can get this fatal error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message blah blah.

How do we catch this specific error, log it, but allow the script to continue to run? Anyone has idea regarding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// run some code

try{
   // run code that throws the exception
}
catch(MongoConnectionException $e)
{
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    // or other logging capabilities
}

// keep running script.
```

Comment: Just to add... One really easy way to log it is to use the php function error_log like so:
error_log($e->getMessage());

Comment: Added to the answer. Thnx @Eric.

Answer (score 2):

catch the exception!!!

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 1):

More generally on this subject, a little caution is required, as standard PHP fatal errors are not automatically converted into exceptions, this modified a little from [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php) should go some way to mitigate this.

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");

try {
    /* Trigger exception */
    strpos();
}
catch (ErrorException $e) {
    // deal with the error
}
```

Comment: Even this is not catching Time Limit reached Fatal Error. Is there any other ways to catch it?